# Inserting items in an array every nth place in octave / matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

How can I insert elements in an array *(a2)* every **nth** place in *(a1)*

Example: Logic

```
a1 = [1,10,2,20,3,30,4,40,5,50];
a2 = [100,200,300,400,500];
n=3 % n would be the position to place the elements found in (a2) every **nth** position in (a1).  
*n is the starting position at which the array a2 is inserted into a1*
```

The **new** *a1* if **n=3** after inserting *a2* into it would look like

```
a1 = [1,10,100,2,20,200,3,30,300,4,40,400,5,50,500];
```

The **new** *a1* if **n=2** after inserting *a2* into it would look like

```
a1 = [1,100,10,2,200,20,3,300,30,4,400,40,5,500,50];
```

The **new** *a1* if **n=1** after inserting *a2* into it would look like

```
a1 = [100,1,10,200,2,20,300,3,30,400,4,40,500,5,50];
```

I tried

```
a1(1:3:end,:) = a2;
```

but I get dimensions mismatch error.

Please note this is just an example so I can't just calculate an answer **I need to insert the data into the array**.  **n** is the starting position at which the array **a2** is inserted into **a1**

Comment: From your examples, it seems that you're not inserting the elements of `a2` at every `nth` position, you're inserting them at every `3rd` position starting with position `n`. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @beaker Yes in this instance you are correct

Comment: "in this instance" implies that other instances behave differently. Unless you tell us what the behavior should be in all instances, I don't think anyone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First allocate an array of the combined size, then insert both original arrays to required indices. With `a2` it is easy, you can just use `n:n:end`. To get indices for `a1` you can subtract the set of `a2` indices from the set of all indices:

```
a1 = [1,10,2,20,3,30,4,40,5,50];
a2 = [100,200,300,400,500];
n = 3;

res = zeros(1,length(a1)+length(a2));
res(n:n:n*length(a2)) = a2;
a1Ind = setdiff(1:length(res), n:n:n*length(a2));
res(a1Ind) = a1;

>> res
res =
     1    10   100     2    20   200     3    30   300     4    40   400     5    50   500
```

Comment: thanks but when I change your value of n to n=2 or n=1 I get an error "error: A(I) = X: X must have the same size as I" it looks like it doesn't work for Nth place 1 or 2

Comment: Ok, edited the answer to make it more generic. You just had to limit the set of `a2` indices.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use *circshift* to shift the row you want on top

```
orig_array=[1:5;10:10:50;100:100:500;1000:1000:5000];
row_on_top=3 %row to be on top

[a1_rows a1_cols]=size(orig_array)
a1 = circshift(orig_array, [-mod(row_on_top,a1_rows)+1, 0])
Anew = zeros(1,a1_rows*a1_cols)
for n=1:1:a1_rows
  n
  insert_idx=[n:a1_rows:a1_cols*a1_rows]  %create insert idx
  Anew(insert_idx(1:a1_cols))=a1(n,:) %insert only 1:a1_cols values

end
Anew=Anew(:)
```